# Error when importing a SQL file using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, joomla, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I am not proficient in MySQL and phpMyAdmin and got this error when trying to import my SQL file to a new installation of WAMP. I was developing a joomla website on my local pc and after completion, decided to launch it online with Rochen web hosting. When importing this into my Cpanel, it gave me the error below.

Error

Static analysis:

1. errors were found during analysis.

   A closing bracket was expected. (near ")" at position 276)

SQL query:

- Database: `kwadi`.

Table structure for table `iq2rf_assets`:

```
CREATE TABLE `iq2rf_assets` 
( 
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key', 
   `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT 
)
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ')' at line 14

I tried to resolve with their support but their advice was for me to upgrade my WAMP Server on my local pc to the one that has MariaDB in it and try extract. Now after installing the new WAMP server i am faced with the same issue when trying to import my back up db using phpmyadmin.

It is giving me the same error. I do not know what to do.

Need assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE iq2rf_assets ( id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key', parent_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0')
```

You do not have a comment on the second field (parent_id), yet you are using the keyword "COMMENT" only to be closing the query after that. Remove it and you're good to go

Comment: thank you very much for the feedback. I did that, tried to import the sql file and now am getting this error below.    Error

-- Dumping data for table `iq2rf_assets`
--

INSERT INTO `iq2rf_assets` (`id`, `parent_id`, `lft`, `rgt`, `level`, `name`, `title`, `rules`) VALUES
(1, 0, 0, 143, 0, 'root.1', 'Root Asset', '{"core.login.site":{"6":1,"2":1},"core.login.admin":{"6":1},"core.login.offline":

  MySQL said: Documentation
#1054 - Unknown column 'lft' in 'field list

Comment: That is because you are only creating the table with two fields, id and parent_id. You do not have lft, rgt, level etc in your table.

Comment: If I was able to help you, please mark my answer as the correct one. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The assets table has more fields than the 2 fields shown in your post.
This is the reason for the failed import, check your export.

Comment: thanks very much. i managed to locate the other fields. it's phpmyadmin messing up the export file. By the way do you know where i can get the default fields? I have developed the website on joomla after installing wamp. I managed to get the assets table created. I am now after the default fields for the following table, XXXX_categories.

Comment: INSERT INTO `xxxx_categories` (`id`, `asset_id`, `parent_id`, `lft`, `rgt`, `level`, `path`, `extension`, `title`, `alias`, `note`, `description`, `published`, `checked_out`, `checked_out_time`, `access`, `params`, `metadesc`, `metakey`, `metadata`, `created_user_id`, `created_time`, `modified_user_id`, `modified_time`, `hits`, `language`, `version`)